# Gammu - Entry is empty, cannot set SMSC

Tags: linux, networking, sms, gammu, wwan

Short description:

- when I try to send a SMS I receive the error: "Failed to get SMSC number from phone."
- so I try to set the SMSC number and I receive the error: "Entry is empty."

Commnads are:

```
root@mail:/home/victor# echo "Dragon Ball super is Awsome!" | gammu --sendsms TEXT +40740863629
Failed to get SMSC number from phone.
root@mail:/home/victor# gammu setsmsc 1 "+40748438759"
Entry is empty.
```

Result of command gammu identify is:

```
root@mail:/home/victor# gammu identify
Device               : /dev/ttyUSB0
Manufacturer         : Qualcomm
Model                : unknown (HSDPA Modem)
Firmware             : 01.02.04  1  [Nov 27 2015 14:33:39]
SIM IMSI             : +CIMI:226102317883481
```

Maybe my device is not supported by gammu?

This is my configuration file ... I tried different configuration:

```
[gammu]

port = /dev/ttyUSB0
model =
connection = at19200
synchronizetime = no
logfile = /var/log/gammu.log
logformat = textall
use_locking =
gammuloc =
```

I used my Ubuntu gammu version 1.37.

Comment: I can use `-smsnumber +33695000695` when sending the message but it work. I have not found how to set the default smsc, I have the same issue. Did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I just read the manual of the device, the solution is to load the right driver:

```
modprobe usbserial vendor=0x5c6 product=0x6000
```

After this the SMS can be send, no need to set SMSC manualy

Comment: Can you please explain how to revert the command and what the command does. This may break my configuration if not appropriate to my device?

Comment: modprobe loads a module intro the linux kernel, to revert use the command rmmod